# Swift/IOS8 error: "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None"

Tags: swift, ios8

I know there are already a couple issues on this, but I can't figure it out. The previous solved issues would suggest that 'profileViewController' is nil, but I don't know why that would be the case. The UI is completely programmatic, no IB. Getting:

> "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None"

on pushViewController() in the following code:

```
class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController {

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = "Favorites"
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "MikeIcon")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let profileButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
        profileButton.frame = CGRectMake(60, 300, 200, 44)
        profileButton.setTitle("View Profile", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        profileButton.addTarget(self, action: "showProfile:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(profileButton)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func showProfile(sender: UIButton) {
        let profileViewController = ProfileViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

    }
```

Here's the relevant portion of **AppDelegate.swift**:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let feedViewController = FeedViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        let favoritesViewController = FavoritesViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        let profileViewController = ProfileViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController

        tabBarController.viewControllers = [feedViewController, favoritesViewController, profileViewController]        


        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try using a different initializer? Why not just `ProfileViewController()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Navigation Controller object `self.navigationController` `nil`?

The variable type on the `navigationController` property is an unwrapped optional.  If your View Controller is not inside a `UINavigationController` that would be the problem.

To prevent the crash code along the following lines should be written:

```
if (self.navigationController)
{
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true) 
}
```

Alternatively you could write the code as:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

The `?` operator will prevent any further code from being executed, if `self.navigationController` evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, the NavigationController is nil, so the above test does catch it and prevent the exception. I'll have to go back and see why that is. I'm trying to follow the "Try IOS" course on Codeschool and convert their example to Swift on the fly, so I don't always get to see their entire code base.

Comment: My fault, I missed where the Codeschool course changed from the UITabViewController to the UINavigationController.